# How to parse array into array JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

first of all I wanted to know if the structure of the json is correct, you can find the JSON here:

http://demo8461125.mockable.io/whitemage

if it is correct I would like to know how to parse "PANINI" , is an array inside an array "tipopietanza"

```java
 JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("pietanze");
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                            {

                                JSONArray pietanze = response.getJSONArray("PANINI");
                                List<Pietanze> listapietanze =new ArrayList<>(pietanze.length());

                                for(int j=0;j<pietanze.length();j++)
                                {
                                    Pietanze tmp = new Pietanze();
                                    tmp.setNome(pietanze.getJSONObject(j).getString("nomepietanza"));
                                    listapietanze.add(tmp);
                                }
                                expandableListDetail.put(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipopietanza"), listapietanze);
                            }
```

Comment: inside for loop, 

JSONObject jsonChild = arr.getJSONObject(i);
 
if(jsonChild.has("PANINI"){
   JSONArray pietanze = jsonChild .getJSONArray("PANINI");
}

Comment: "I wanted to know if the structure of the json is correct" - Use one of the many online JSON Formatters/Validators.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya i think you mean to edit like this https://codeshare.io/UbKVU but it don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON structure is okay.

You need to do minor changes in your code for getting list properly.

```java
JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("pietanze");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);

    if(jsonObject.has("PANINI")) {
        JSONArray paniniJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("PANINI");
        List<Panini> listPanini = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int j = 0; j < paniniJsonArray.length(); j++) {
            Panini panini = new Panini();
            panini.setId(paniniJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
            panini.setNomepietanza(paniniJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("nomepietanza"));
            panini.setPrezzo(paniniJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("prezzo"));
            listPanini.add(panini);
        }
        expandableListDetail.put(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipopietanza"), listPanini);
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows me the ListDetail, but when I try to open it the app crashes without showing me the contents of the list

Comment: @Mattek can you please provide more of your code or send me activity code where I can check rest code. Because i don't think so it is crashing because of list and send some crash log too.

Comment: Sorry my bad, obviously the program expected all the fields, and I have forgotten a field of "panini" in the jsp! IT WORKS!

Comment: @Mattek If it was correct answer, then please approve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work, but I suggest just use `Gson`:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<TipiPaniniAndServizi>>(){}.getType();
List<TipiPaniniAndServizi> tipiPaniniAndServizi = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

And save your time from manipulate `JSON`, just think about your java objects.